# Raku zip operator & space

Tags: raku

I found this one liner which joins same lines from multiple files.
How to add a space between two lines?

If line 1 from file A is blue and line 1 from file B is sky, a get bluesky,
but need blue sky.

`say $_ for [Z~] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is using the side-effect of `.Str` on a `List` to add spaces between the elements:

```
say .Str for [Z] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines
```

The `Z` will create 2 element `List` objects, which the `.Str` will then stringify.

Or even shorter:

```
.put for [Z] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines
```

where the `.put` will call the `.Str` for you and output that.

If you want anything else inbetween, then you could probably use `.join`:

```
say .join(",") for [Z] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines
```

would put comma's between the words.

Comment: And, building on the above, the slightly-longer-but-more-explicit option is `say .join(' ') for [Z] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines`

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: definitely don't do this in anything approaching real code.  Use (one of) the readable ways in Liz's answer.

If you *really* want to use the same structure as `[Z~]` – that is, an operator modified by the Zip meta-operator, all inside the Reduce meta-operator – you can.  But it's not pretty:

```
say $_ for [Z[&(*~"\x20"~*)]] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines
```

Here's how that works: `Z` can take an operator, so we need to give it an operator that concatenates two strings with a space in between.  But there's no operator like that built in.  No problem – we can turn any function into an infix operator by surrounding it with `[ ]` (the [infix form](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Infix_form)).

So all we need is a function that joins two strings with a space between them.  That *also* doesn't exist, but we can create one: `* ~ ' ' ~ *`.  So, we should be able to shove that into our infix form and pass the whole thing to the Zip operator `Z[* ~ ' ' ~ *]`.

Except that doesn't work.  Because Zip isn't *really* expecting an infix form, we need to give it a hint that we're passing in a function … that is, we need to put our function into a callable [context](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts) with `&( )`, which gets us to `Z[&(* ~ ' ' ~ *)]`.

That Zip expression does what we want when used in infix position – but it **still** doesn't work once we put it back into the Reduce/`[ ]` operator that we want to use.  This time, the problem is due to something that may or may not be a bug – even after [discussing it with jnthn on github](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4423), I'm still not sure whether this behavior is intended/correct.

Specifically, the issue is that the Reduction meta-operator [doesn't allow whitespace](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L3873) – even in strings.  Thus, we need to replace `* ~ ' ' ~ *` with `*~"\c[space]"~*` or `*~"\x20"~*` (where `\x20` is the hex value of   in Unicode/ASCII).  Since we've come this far into obfuscated code, I figure we might as well go all the way.  And that gets us back to

```
say $_ for [Z[&(*~"\x20"~*)]] @*ARGS.map: *.IO.lines
```

Again, I'm *not* recommending that you do this.  (And, if you do, you could at least make it slightly more readable by saving the `* ~ ' ' ~ *` function as a named variable in the previous line, which at least gets you whitespace.  But, really, just use one of Liz's suggestions).

I just thought this gives a useful window into some of the darker and more interesting corners of Raku's strangely consistent behavior.